# How to use searchDisplayController with objects of class

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a class, with some `objects` (Title, price, modifier), And I have an `NSArray` of `objects` of this class.

I load this `NSArray` into `UITableView`. How can I use `searchDisplayController`?
I can't understand.. array have only addresses (to objects in my class) and how i can sort it by predicate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can explain with an example

Let consider my code is like below

**Without NSPredicate**

```
NSMutableArray *oldSkoolFiltered = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (Book *book in bookshelf) {
    if ([book.publisher isEqualToString:@"Apress"]) {
        [oldSkoolFiltered addObject:book];
    }
}
```

**Applied NSPredicate**

```
NSPredicate *predicate = 
  [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"publisher == %@", @"Apress" ];
NSArray *filtered  = [bookshelf filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Comment: this example will really help you http://www.apptite.be/blog/ios/3-searching-in-tables-sample-iphone-application-contacts-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

I think you have forgot the type casting of the array to the class name. 
Try to do like this

```
cell.textLabel.text=((ClassName *)[arrOfObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]).Title;
```

and for predicate i will suggest you to go through this [example](http://www.peterfriese.de/using-nspredicate-to-filter-data/)